# Audio slider using arrow keys in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an audio slider using arrow keys(left,right). But the below developed code did not work. Where am i doing wrong in below code?

```
<audio id="lessonTrack" controls>
  <source src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>


$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = e.keyCode;
    if (x === 39) {
      audio.currentTime += 2;
    } else if (x === 37) {
      audio.currentTime -= 2;
    }
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cchidambaram85/notvhc4j/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code I think you forget to add **jQuery Library** otherwise your code is working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = e.keyCode;
    if (x === 39) {
      audio.currentTime += 2;
    } else if (x === 37) {
      audio.currentTime -= 2;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="lessonTrack" controls>
  <source src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Here is the code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJyejO

Comment: No i don't think it's working. I think he want to slide from one to another. which is not happening in his code. OP said:- `I want to make an audio slider using arrow keys(left,right).`

Comment: Run code snippet and click on the opened container then click left and right and check its working.